Beginning requests become trapped in a never-ending cycle and are unable to reach the parse callback
This is the code I wrote:
# spider.py
def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(url=self.url, method='POST', callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True, flags=['this is the start request method'])


def parse(self, response):
    logging.info('started parsing')
    l = ItemLoader(FeedItem())
    json_response = json.loads(response.text)

    l.add_value('feed', json_response)

    yield l.load_items()


    yield scrapy.Request(url=self.url, method='POST', callback=self.parse, flags=['this is the parse method'])

# middlewares.py
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    sinceId = self.cur.execute('SELECT sinceId FROM proposal').fetchone()
    jobT = self.cur.execute('SELECT jobT FROM proposal').fetchone()
    if not sinceId:
        body = self.body.encode('utf-8')
        request = request.replace(body=body)
        spider.logger.info(f'{request.flags}')
        spider.logger.info('Returning unchanged request')
        return request
    
    body = re.sub(r'("sinceId":")(\d+)(")', '"sinceId":' + f'"{sinceId}"', self.body) # change sinceId
    body = re.sub(r'("jobTime":")(\d+)(")', '"jobTime":' + f'"{jobT}"', body) # changed jobTime
    body = self.body.encode('utf-8')
    spider.logger.info('Body changed')

    request = request.replace(body=body)
    spider.logger.info(f'{request.flags}')
    spider.logger.info('Returning changed request')
    return request

def spider_opened(self, spider):
    self.body = '{"query":"\n          query($queryParams: UserSavedSearchesParams) {\n            userSavedSearches(params: $queryParams) {\n              results {\n                id\n                uid:id\n                title\n                ciphertext\n                description\n                type\n                recno\n                freelancersToHire\n                duration\n                durationLabel\n                engagement\n                amount {\n                  amount:displayValue\n                }\n                createdOn:createdDateTime\n                publishedOn:publishedDateTime\n                renewedOn:renewedDateTime\n                prefFreelancerLocation\n                prefFreelancerLocationMandatory\n                connectPrice\n                client {\n                  totalHires\n                  totalPostedJobs\n                  totalSpent {\n                    rawValue\n                    currency\n                    displayValue\n                  }\n                  paymentVerificationStatus,\n                  location {\n                    country\n                  }\n                  totalReviews\n                  totalFeedback\n                  companyRid\n                  edcUserId\n                  lastContractRid\n                  companyOrgUid\n                  hasFinancialPrivacy\n                }\n                enterpriseJob\n                premium\n                jobTs:jobTime\n                skills {\n                  id\n                  name\n                  prettyName\n                  highlighted\n                }\n                contractorTier\n                jobStatus\n                relevanceEncoded\n                totalApplicants\n                proposalsTier\n                isLocal:local\n                locations {\n                  city\n                  country\n                }\n                isApplied:applied\n                attrs {\n                  id\n                  uid:id\n                  prettyName:prefLabel\n                  parentSkillId\n                  prefLabel\n                  highlighted\n                  freeText\n                }\n                hourlyBudget {\n                  type\n                  min\n                  max\n                }\n                clientRelation {\n                  companyRid\n                  companyName\n                  edcUserId\n                  lastContractPlatform\n                  lastContractRid\n                  lastContractTitle\n                }\n                totalFreelancersToHire\n                contractToHire\n              }\n              paging {\n                  total\n                  count\n                  resultSetTs:resultSetTime\n              }\n            }\n          }\n        ","variables":{"queryParams":{"sinceId":"1015914410","jobTime":"1728208823055","paging":"0;20"}}}'
    self.body = self.body.replace('\n','\\n')
    self.con = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
    self.cur = self.con.cursor()
    self.cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS proposal(title, description, _type, duration, salary, sinceID, jobT, UNIQUE(title, description, _type, duration, salary, sinceID, jobT))')

    spider.logger.info("Spider opened: %s" % spider.name)

The way I expect it to work is:

It sends the initial request.
Gets the body modified.
Return a callback to the parse method.
...

However, it remains stuck indefinitely on the second step.
Here's the traceback:
2024-10-08 11:12:30 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.11.2 started (bot: feed)
2024-10-08 11:12:31 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 5.3.0.0, libxml2 2.11.7, cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.9.1, w3lib 2.2.1, Twisted 24.7.0, Python 3.12.6 (tags/v3.12.6:a4a2d2b, Sep  6 2024, 20:11:23) [MSC v.1940 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 24.2.1 (OpenSSL 3.3.2 3 Sep 2024), cryptography 43.0.1, Platform Windows-11-10.0.22631-SP0
2024-10-08 11:12:31 [scrapy.addons] INFO: Enabled addons:
[]
2024-10-08 11:12:31 [asyncio] DEBUG: Using selector: SelectSelector
2024-10-08 11:12:31 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor
2024-10-08 11:12:31 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using asyncio event loop: asyncio.windows_events._WindowsSelectorEventLoop
2024-10-08 11:12:31 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 443b0e3cce0e2a7f
2024-10-08 11:12:31 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2024-10-08 11:12:31 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'feed',
 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 80,
 'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'feed.spiders',
 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['feed.spiders'],
 'TWISTED_REACTOR': 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'}
2024-10-08 11:12:32 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'feed.middlewares.FeedDownloaderMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2024-10-08 11:12:32 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2024-10-08 11:12:32 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['feed.pipelines.FeedPipeline']
2024-10-08 11:12:32 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2024-10-08 11:12:32 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-10-08 11:12:32 [feed] INFO: Spider opened: feed
2024-10-08 11:12:32 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2024-10-08 11:12:32 [feed] INFO: ['this is the start request method']
2024-10-08 11:12:32 [feed] INFO: Returning unchanged request
2024-10-08 11:12:33 [feed] INFO: ['this is the start request method']
2024-10-08 11:12:33 [feed] INFO: Returning unchanged request
2024-10-08 11:12:34 [feed] INFO: ['this is the start request method']
2024-10-08 11:12:34 [feed] INFO: Returning unchanged request
2024-10-08 11:12:35 [feed] INFO: ['this is the start request method']
2024-10-08 11:12:35 [feed] INFO: Returning unchanged request
2024-10-08 11:12:36 [feed] INFO: ['this is the start request method']
2024-10-08 11:12:36 [feed] INFO: Returning unchanged request

I don't get why it sends multiple requests and never gives a callback.
EDIT:
spider.py
name='test'
url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'   
def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(url=self.url, method='POST', body="{'key': 'value'}", callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    self.log(response.json())

# middlewares.py 
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    new_body = "{'key1': 'new_value1', 'key2': 'new_value2'}"
    request = request.replace(
        body=new_body,
        dont_filter = True
    )
    time.sleep(3)
    spider.logger.info('body changed')
    return request

I get into a loop:
2024-10-09 12:15:37 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2024-10-09 12:15:37 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-10-09 12:15:37 [testik] INFO: Spider opened: testik
2024-10-09 12:15:37 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2024-10-09 12:15:40 [testik] INFO: body changed
2024-10-09 12:15:43 [testik] INFO: body changed
2024-10-09 12:15:46 [testik] INFO: body changed
2024-10-09 12:15:49 [testik] INFO: body changed


This works as documented for process_request.

Why are you returning the request in your middleware process_request function? I think you want to return None there.

You returned a request in the process_request method of your downloadermiddleware, which will not continue processing your origin request, but will put the modified request into the queue waiting for processing. So you are in a loop of:

start_requests send a request to the scheduler
Scrapy engine get the request and give it to downloadermiddleware
process_request of downloadermiddleware cancels the request and
put a new request to the scheduler
Scrapy engine get the request and give it to downloadermiddleware (same as step 2).

This is from the document about the process_request method of downloadermiddleware:

This method is called for each request that goes through the download
middleware.
process_request() should either: return None, return a Response
object, return a Request object, or raise IgnoreRequest.
If it returns None, Scrapy will continue processing this request,
executing all other middlewares until, finally, the appropriate
downloader handler is called the request performed (and its response
downloaded).
If it returns a Response object, Scrapy won’t bother calling any other
process_request() or process_exception() methods, or the appropriate
download function; it’ll return that response. The process_response()
methods of installed middleware is always called on every response.
If it returns a Request object, Scrapy will stop calling
process_request methods and reschedule the returned request. Once the
newly returned request is performed, the appropriate middleware chain
will be called on the downloaded response.
If it raises an IgnoreRequest exception, the process_exception()
methods of installed downloader middleware will be called. If none of
them handle the exception, the errback function of the request
(Request.errback) is called. If no code handles the raised exception,
it is ignored and not logged (unlike other exceptions).


How do I make it ignore the already processed request in the process_request?

You should return None after you modified the request in process_request, scrapy will continue processing this modified request and self.parse will be called to handle it after the downloader of scrapy get the response.

It doesn't seem to modify the body (see the edit).

The downloader_middlewares is on

@TEOTU I mean, you should return None after the line spider.logger.info('Returning unchanged request') in process_request. In this case you make no change to your request, so you should not return a request object.

The log is a bit misleading, I'm actually changing it, just with the default body I've initialized but didn't modify. Could you tell me why in the edit, the parameters don't change?

@TEOTU I made a mistake in my first comment. In process_request, it will continue processing the origin request if you return None, not the modified request. Sorry buddy.

How do I escape the loop then, where I return the request and the modified request goes back to the scrapy engine and then back to the process_request?

Return None if you change nothing of the request, or return the modified request instead.  You returned request object in both cases, that's why you entered in the loop.

In the edit (see the edit), I return only 1 request and it is a modified body, but still, I get into a loop. Why?

Because you have only one case. No matter you modified the request or not, it returns a new request, so you get into the loop again. You should add a case returning None when you don't need to modify the request.
